# Button working then failing

Tags: button, lua, coronasdk

My problem is very confusing, and there does not seem to be an easy solution that I see. When I go into my 'Settings' scene There are 2 buttons 'aboutButton' and 'userSettingsButton' These buttons lead to scenes called 'about' and 'user'. At this scene ( looking at the, about button and user settings ) I am able to click either button and it responds to anywhere on the text that I click it. On this same page I have a return home button that works also. When I click the about button everything works as it normally should, I 'goto' that scene and then can go back using my 'goBackButton' at the 'about' scene and nothing with the buttons stop working. When I 'goto' my 'user' scene everything appears to work and ( including the 'goBackButton' on that scene ) but after I go back to the 'Settings scene' if I attempt to back back into either the 'About the App' or 'User Settings' I am only able to activate that button by either clicking on the very top edge ( for the 'About the App' ) and for the 'User Settings' I can only activate it by clicking on the very bottom of the app.

I know this seems like a VERY VERY strange problem and I am on a Windows machine using the free version of Corona SDK ( if that information would have anything to do with it ) But like I said normally all of the buttons work fine I have only text made buttons in my program and 'myData' ( the replacement to global variables ) is used when I 'goto' the 'User Settings', so let me know if there is any other information that I would need to give for someone to help me with this program ALL of the code DOES NOT throw ANY ERRORS AT ALL.EVERYTHING WORKS FINE UNTIL I enter the User Settings, then somethings after that work and others don't.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this and I appreciate any help or advice on how I could fix this.

I am thinking that It might be a problem to do with memory.. I insert 28 items for the display into my sceneGroup, so tell me if that assumption is could be correct.

Here is the code for settings home :

```
local widget = require("widget")
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create ()
    local g = self.view
end

function returnHomeButtonOptions()
    local options = 
    {
    effect = "slideDown",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.HomeScreen", options)
end

function aboutButtonOptions()
    local options = 
    {
    effect = "slideUp",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.Settings.about", options)
end

function userButtonOptions()
    local options =
    {
    effect = "slideRight",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.Settings.user", options)
end

local function returnHomeButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        returnHomeButtonOptions()
    end
end

local function aboutButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        aboutButtonOptions()
    end
end

local function userButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        userButtonOptions()
    end
end

local returnHomeButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "Return Home",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.8125,
    y = display.contentWidth * 1.5625,
    onEvent = returnHomeButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 16,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}

local aboutButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "About The App",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.5,
    y = 150,
    onEvent = aboutButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 30,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}

local userButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "User Settings",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.5,
    y = 300,
    onEvent = userButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 30,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}


local backBlock = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth * 2, display.contentHeight * 3)
local block2 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 100, 100, 100)
local block3 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 100, 100, 100)
local block4 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.5, 10, 100, 100)
local block5 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 200, 100, 100)
local block6 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 200, 100, 100)
local block7 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.5, 490, 100, 100)
local block8 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 300, 100, 100)
local block9 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 300, 100, 100)
local block10 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 400, 100, 100)
local block11 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 400, 100, 100)
block2:rotate(45)
block3:rotate(45)
block4:rotate(45)
block5:rotate(45)
block6:rotate(45)
block7:rotate(45)
block8:rotate(45)
block9:rotate(45)
block10:rotate(45)
block11:rotate(45)
block2.alpha = 0.2
block3.alpha = 0.2
block4.alpha = 0.2
block5.alpha = 0.2
block6.alpha = 0.2
block7.alpha = 0.2
block8.alpha = 0.2
block9.alpha = 0.2
block10.alpha = 0.2
block11.alpha = 0.2
backBlock.alpha = 0.1

function scene:show (event)

    local g = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "will") then

        display.setStatusBar( display.DarkStatusBar )

        g:insert(backBlock)
        g:insert(block2)
        g:insert(block3)
        g:insert(block4)
        g:insert(block5)
        g:insert(block6)
        g:insert(block7)
        g:insert(block8)
        g:insert(block9)
        g:insert(block10)
        g:insert(block11)
        g:insert(returnHomeButton)
        g:insert(aboutButton)
        g:insert(userButton)

    end
end


scene:addEventListener("create", scene)
scene:addEventListener("show", scene)



return scene
```

AND here is the code for user

```
local widget = require("widget")
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create ()
    local g = self.view
end

function returnHomeButtonOptions()
    local options = 
    {
    effect = "slideDown",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.HomeScreen", options)
end

function aboutButtonOptions()
    local options = 
    {
    effect = "slideUp",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.Settings.about", options)
end

function userButtonOptions()
    local options =
    {
    effect = "slideRight",
    time = 500,
    }
    composer.gotoScene("MainContent.Settings.user", options)
end

local function returnHomeButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        returnHomeButtonOptions()
    end
end

local function aboutButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        aboutButtonOptions()
    end
end

local function userButtonHandler(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "ended") then
        userButtonOptions()
    end
end

local returnHomeButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "Return Home",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.8125,
    y = display.contentWidth * 1.5625,
    onEvent = returnHomeButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 16,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}

local aboutButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "About The App",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.5,
    y = 150,
    onEvent = aboutButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 30,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}

local userButton = widget.newButton
{
    label = "User Settings",
    x = display.contentWidth * 0.5,
    y = 300,
    onEvent = userButtonHandler,
    fontSize = 30,
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } }
}


local backBlock = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth * 2, display.contentHeight * 3)
local block2 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 100, 100, 100)
local block3 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 100, 100, 100)
local block4 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.5, 10, 100, 100)
local block5 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 200, 100, 100)
local block6 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 200, 100, 100)
local block7 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.5, 490, 100, 100)
local block8 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 300, 100, 100)
local block9 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 300, 100, 100)
local block10 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.25, 400, 100, 100)
local block11 = display.newRect(display.contentWidth * 0.75, 400, 100, 100)
block2:rotate(45)
block3:rotate(45)
block4:rotate(45)
block5:rotate(45)
block6:rotate(45)
block7:rotate(45)
block8:rotate(45)
block9:rotate(45)
block10:rotate(45)
block11:rotate(45)
block2.alpha = 0.2
block3.alpha = 0.2
block4.alpha = 0.2
block5.alpha = 0.2
block6.alpha = 0.2
block7.alpha = 0.2
block8.alpha = 0.2
block9.alpha = 0.2
block10.alpha = 0.2
block11.alpha = 0.2
backBlock.alpha = 0.1

function scene:show (event)

    local g = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "will") then

        display.setStatusBar( display.DarkStatusBar )

        g:insert(backBlock)
        g:insert(block2)
        g:insert(block3)
        g:insert(block4)
        g:insert(block5)
        g:insert(block6)
        g:insert(block7)
        g:insert(block8)
        g:insert(block9)
        g:insert(block10)
        g:insert(block11)
        g:insert(returnHomeButton)
        g:insert(aboutButton)
        g:insert(userButton)

    end
end


scene:addEventListener("create", scene)
scene:addEventListener("show", scene)



return scene
```

There you can see my code for the user.lua and the settingsHome.lua

Thanks for reading this and helping me out    :)

Comment: If I comment the handlers for the buttons in that 'user' scene then leave the buttons alone the SAME problem will occur, If I comment out the buttons in that scene and then leave the handlers alone the problem with the buttons mentioned above will not occur..

Comment: can you show parts of your codes where the problem occurs? Maybe then we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return true` the functions that handle the buttons actions.

Comment: Alright I will try it, why is it that return true would work though?

Comment: this kind of helps explain it to me..    https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/35479-what-is-return-true-really-for/